# cron jobs php code in file

Tags: php, cron

I have a php script whose name is XYZ.php.  When I load that file in browser it executes a form every 5 seconds automatically.  I want cron to run this script every  hour and I don't have any problem in setting up cron job in cpanel but I don't know how to write php codes in XYZ.php file to work with cron.

In my php file there is one form which executes random name from database every hour and submit it to database once again.

So in form there is only one field i.e name of users which needs to be run from cron.

Please guide how can I do that.  If I can open that file for 30 seconds using cron then it will do the work I am looking for.

**Edit:**

This is my form javascript will automatically submit it in 5 seconds so how to execute this script from cron

```
<form name="form1" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']; ?>"> 
  <input name="lastlogin" type="text" id="lastlogin" value="<?php echo (time()); ?>" size="40" />
  <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="submit" /> 
</form>
```

Comment: this is my form javascript will automatically submit it in 5 seconds so how to execute this script from cron                                     <form name="form1" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']; ?>">
        <input name="lastlogin" type="text" id="lastlogin" value="<?php echo (time()); ?>" size="40" />
       
     <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="submit" />
  
    </form>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cron is a tool designed to execute command line programs. You appear to have a JavaScript-based web application: you simply can't use that. While you'd be able to retrieve the page using a command line web browser, the dynamic part would not be executed.

The obvious answer is to write a command line PHP script. There's a full chapter about it in the PHP manual: [Using PHP from the command line](http://es.php.net/cli). I recommend this section:

- http://es.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.usage.php

Comment: here i have posted only javascript part of form everything is there in php except cron part. a;ready i have given the full path in cpanel cron with timing and all but what i should write in XYZ.php file so that cron can execute it or is there any way i can open that file for 10 seconds evrytime

Comment: Have you understood my answer?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a form post at all.  Have your script file do the database work when executed.  Then have your cron job be:

```
php XYZ.php
```

If you want the database work to be done from a cron job and when a user goes to a web page and submits a form, create a class in XYZ.php that does the work.  Then have a script called XYZ-cron.php that creates the class and does the work.  Then create a script ran by Apache called XYZ-form.php that renders a form and handles POST requests to do the same work, using the class from XYZ.php.

Comment: your answer was perfect .exactly you are understanding my problem.please give some php code how to do this i have already posted my form so i think you can guide me please